# Are They Similar Polygons?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

## Task

Given the x,y coordinates (coordinates are guaranteed to be integers) of the vertices of two [simple polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon) in clockwise or anti-clockwise order. Output a Truthy value if both the polygons are [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)) otherwise a Falsy value

A simple polygon is a polygon that does not intersect itself and has no holes. That is, it is a flat shape consisting of straight, non-intersecting line segments or "sides" that are joined pairwise to form a single closed path. If the sides intersect then the polygon is not simple. Two edges meeting at a corner are required to form a an angle that is not not straight (180°)

Two polygons are similar if either polygon can be rescaled, repositioned, and reflected, so as to coincide precisely with the other polygon.

## Testcases

**Input**

```
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)]
[(-1, 0), (2, 1), (1, 4), (-2, 3)]
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2lJj.png)

**Output**

```
Truthy
```

---

**Input**

```
[(2, 3), (0, 0), (4, 0)]
[(-3, 0), (-2, 2), (0, 1), (1, -1), (-1, -2), (-2, -2)]
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fOUn.png)

**Output**

```
Falsy
```

---

**Input**

```
[(1, 4), (1, 3), (0, 2), (1, 1), (-3, 2)]
[(2, 0), (2, -1), (3, -1), (4, -2), (-2, -2)]
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N3hM.png)

**Output**

```
Falsy
```

---

**Input**

```
[(-1, 0), (2, 1), (1, 4), (-2, 3)]
[(1, 4), (2, 1), (-1, 0), (-2, 3)]
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMFHp.png)

**Output**

```
Truthy
```

---

**Input**

```
[(-2, 0), (-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 3), (1, 0)]
[(5, 4), (4, 2), (3, 2), (2, 1), (5, 1)]
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLxMF.png)

**Output**

```
Truthy
```

---

**Input**

```
[(2, 13), (4, 8), (2, 3), (0, 8)]
[(0, 0), (5, 0), (8, 4), (3, 4)]
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YRst.png)

**Output**

```
Falsy
```

---

**Input**

```
[(-1, 0), (-5, 3), (-5, 9), (-1, 6)]
[(0, 0), (5, 0), (8, 4), (3, 4)]
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUSJs.png)

**Output**

```
Falsy
```

---

**Input**

```
[(0, 0), (1, 2), (1, 0)]
[(2, 0), (2, 2), (3, 0)]
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPDfs.png)

**Output**

```
Truthy
```

---

Comment: This needs way more falsy test cases! For starters: non-similar rhombi (defeats submissions that only check side lengths); non-similar rectangles (defeats submissions that only check angles). Also, I'd suggest cutting down on the diagrams: one or two are enough to get the idea, beyond that I'd rather have all the test data in a convenient text format.

Comment: @Grimmy, thanks for the suggestions working on more testcases.

Comment: Ok @Mukundan and what about the fact that the tests might have different lengths?

Comment: Are all vertices of each polygon guaranteed to be different?

Comment: Is the penultimate test case really falsy?

Comment: In the interests of being self-contained, the definition of "similar" should be included in the spec.

Comment: @Arnauld, Thanks for pointing that out fixed the sixth testcase

Comment: @LuisMendo All vertices of each polygon are guaranteed to be different

Comment: @RGS No, I don't plan on changing the question to be for only polygons with same number of vertices

Comment: Related: [Similar triangles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/194138/20260)

Comment: The pictures you have drawn are great. Are you sure you don't want to include them in the question? You just need to lay them out so they don't use too much space.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 97 bytes (SBCS)

```mathematica
Or@@(Equal@@(a@u/#)&/@(a/@NestList[RotateLeft,v,Length@v]))
a@l_:=Norm[#〚1〛-#〚2〛]&/@l~Subsets~{2}
```

You can [try it online](https://tio.run/##hZLRaoMwFIbvfYpAYdSiaKLeFARvtivpxrY7kZKWdAraMhOFIpY@x/Z4fRCXaKJ2vfDqPybH8/3/0RyzhOSYpXvcHqJya1TbGKz99rUIguXzd4kzrjgorYX@ZPHKCjaEsjClLHo/McxISA7MqIyQHL9YElSxrms4yLZrf3Mq8mhxu/7A2/XXFAXiRcynZJePckcJo5caNe1yBfaYEgDBZ1Gy5AxWulYCH9S1bQC7MUANR4VCbaGNVnVNprpF8pY/u0JNfuDwtrciPbKIZzNAFceapngIvOCMniWra@5nd9NcoQPDkadiJhos9DCzK4QNE6keXv0Hi1gD2@nZY1RlGo420DSycIAGP2iM3NMdVbgzLkYL7sO6ZzdZ3VlVXcNrcwv3HokqiHn3aSd7gNPP4EmyK5fjSFVOvP6/GPkc3/4B)!

The function `a` computes all the pairwise distances between any two vertices of the polygon.

The main function applies this to the first list and to every rotation of the second list, to try and find the corresponding vertices. The rotation of the second list is correct if all the corresponding distances have been scaled accordingly.

Thanks to @J42161217 for saving me some 3 bytes

Comment: @Grimmy I was still updating the link :) It should be correct now!

Comment: a[l_]:= is a@l_:=... Also you don't need the parentheses around Norm

Comment: Are you considering reversals of the list on addition to rotations?

Comment: No, I am not. Are you saying that I should..? I would say it is more than fair to assume that the lists give a path around the polygon in the same direction... I would argue the heart of the challenge is to check for polygon similarity, not to reverse a list...

Comment: @RGS I think considering reversals is necessary this is why the fourth and fifth testcases have a truthy value

Comment: @RGS also you code does not work for testcases where reflections are needed like
`u = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}`
`v = {{2, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}}`
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7fCoIwHEbvfYqBEAkLdd0Jwm66E4u6HENWrBT8Q/rbbmTic9Tj@SBrlVfnwIGPrxFQykZAdRP2zlSBdcFRktpjT@n28FSidhRUhX6wCZ2FNJcDZNUA7NyBAJnJO2CNM9k@oKSaB4EnaF0kad71DfOX@RUv83v3FeKEu5V6uqjrIGGYRmKsQikaxwijyGA0xhiRlZExnv5Fskayxv0/nvqqBeZeY825/QA "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")